# Azure Data Factory - SQL

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I would like to ask you if is it possible to use "output inserted" SQL statement in data flow (Azure Data Factory)

Currently, I am getting an error:

> at Source 'source1': shaded.msdataflow.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement is not allowed in a SELECT statement that is not the immediate source of rows for an INSERT statement.

Using this statement:
[image]

What I did:

I also checked stored procedures but they do not provide any output.

What I want:

I would like to get the 'Id' of row of inserted elements (Insert+Select in one operation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As error shows, insert statement isn't allowed.

As a work around, you can do like this.

1. create a Lookup activity and enter your SQL like this:

[image]

2. create a data flow and create a parameter inside it.
   expression:`@activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.ID`

[image]

3.Inside data flow, choose your table as your source and enter this expression:

```
concat('select ID from dbo.test6 where ID =',toString($ID))
```

4.If your need to do some transform, you can create a `DerivedColumn` and do like this:

[image]

Comment: How about this?`"Select ID from dbo.test6 WHERE ID = '{$ID}'"`